# Hosting WCF and ASP.NET with IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, windows-server-2008

I want to host WCF-services and an ASP.NET MVC4 site with IIS on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Which server roles do I have to install to make this work?

[image]

edit:
**I have installed the roles.
I have internet-connection on my virtual machine.
I can ping from vm to pc.
I can not ping from pc to vm... How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

The roles are not completely updated for these new technologies.

Look at this for WCF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751527.aspx

and this For MVC
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs

Will take a little bit more of a manual installation.

Comment: And which roles does he have to chose in the beginning when installing WS2008R2 ??